# How can I know that the graph is symmetric with respect to the x axis or y axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I know that the graph is symmetric with respect to the x axis or y axis?

- $y=x^4-2x^2-21$
- $9x^2+4y^2=36$
- $y^2=x-4$

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/equation-symmetry.html

Answer (score 1):

If $f(-x) = f(x) $ for all x then the graph is symmetric in the y-axis.

If $-f(x) = f(x) $ for all x then the graph is symmetric in the x-axis

For example a: $y = x^4 - 2x^2 - 21$, if we take $x = -x$, $ y = (-x)^4 - 2(-x)^2 - 21 = x^4 - 2x^2 -21$ hence this function is symmetric in the y-axis.